# Steps to setup proxy server

Tags: windows, linux, squid

I want to setup proxy server on our office. I have two proxy server's available i.e. (SQUID for Linux and WinProxy for Windows).  I have following requirement.

1. All the rule's which I define in proxy server like block some specific sites etc. should likely to work.
2. The "Evolution Mail Client" for linux and "Outlook Express" for windows also should work.

So, can you tell me the guidelines how to achieve both the task especially no.-2 .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Galan: Welcome to StackOverflow! **Why do you want the proxy?** For caching? Or only for blocking pages? Are there labtops in your office?

Answer (score 0):

Squid is a very good option for a **caching proxy**. It has a configuration file to block some specific sites, IPs, domains... and to tell him **which files has to cache**. Making a smart proxy is not easy. But you can find great configurations and tutorials in Google or in [his wiki](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples).

There are two ways for setting up a proxy:

- **Direct proxy**: you have to manually configure **every computer** to use your proxy server.
  This is the easiest option. I recommend you using this.
  Please note, computers that **don't** use the proxy can access all pages (even if they're blocked).
- **Transparent proxy**: this is the most **secure, ideal option** for most cases (including yours). You have to configurate your network and the proxy server to **forward** any requests to it. This is a hard option and very difficult to achieve in your case.

---

About your Evolution and Outlook problem, there can't be **any** problems related to the proxy, don't worry about that.